# Простые словосочетания

Tags: синтаксис, словосочетания

Какие из словосочетаний являются простыми:

1.Длинный товарный поезд
2.Бабушка с добрым лицом
3.Бабушка с тяжёлой авоськой
4.Прыгнуть дальше всех
5.Два красных яблока
6.Учить безусых подростков

Comment: Хорошо бы вначале договориться о терминологии: что мы будем понимать по простым -сложным словосочетанием, ведь четких критериев нет.

Comment: Да, действительно, классификации разные.Простые по данной классификации - нечленимые, сложные - из нескольких простых, т.е. членимые. Я ответила студентке-заочнице, а она не согласна, начала путаться, переспрашивать,вот я и спрашиваю, может,я ошибаюсь, а не она.

Answer (score 3):

Если под простым понимать нечленимое, тогда, на мой взгляд, это: бабушка с добрым лицом, прыгнуть дальше всех, учить безусых подростков.

Comment: А первое? Сочетаниях с неоднородными определениями ведь тоже простые многокомпонентные, тем более, что одно прилагательное качественное, а другое относительное. Это филфак,студенты должны видеть формальную связь и содержательную. Нам важна содержательная:что является длинным?-товарный поезд.Нельзя сказать: поезд был длинным и товарным.

Comment: А вот учить безусых подростков - по-моему, сложное: учить кого?-подростков. Каких?- безусых.Два простых: учить подростков, безусых подростков.

Comment: Здравствуйте,Людмила помогите ,пожалуйста,мне разобраться здесь
http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/30156/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5
если можно напишите ответ на почту,мои вопросы закрывают, и я не могу спрашивать... talib7776@mail.ru